# Is there a way to have fractions with roots?

Tags: python

Is there a way to have fractions (in python) with roots? When I write Fraction(np.sqrt(2), 2), it gives me 1/2, because Fraction takes ints as arguments. I want to have square root of 2 divided by 2, and keep the 2 under the root as to not lose precision while calculating.

Edit: I am using the package "fraction". I couldn't find "fractions" anywhere when I searched for the package to install.

Comment: btw the built-in lib `fractions` is for rational numbers.

Comment: You may find [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) useful.

Comment: Are you talking about the built-in `fractions.Fraction`? `fractions.Fraction(np.sqrt(2), 2)` raises a `TypeError` telling what @quamrana said. How does it give you `1/2`?

Comment: If you can live with the inherent inaccuracy in doing math with an irrational number such as `sqrt(2)`, then you can surely live with the inaccuracy in `sqrt(2)/2`, and forget about fractions completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a comment suggested, I found sqrt in the sympy package. For example sympy.sqrt(8) produces 2*sqrt(2), so it doesn't just keep the number under the root as not to lose precision, it also lets me make operations with it and simplifies it.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely certain if the following is what you want, but, here it goes:

```py
from fractions import Fraction as F
import numpy as np

print(F(F(np.sqrt(2)), 2).limit_denominator(max_denominator=100000))

print(5741/8119)     # with max_denominator=10000
print(33461/47321)
print(np.sqrt(2)/2)
```

Will produce:

```bash
33461/47321
0.7071067865500678
0.7071067813444348
0.7071067811865476
```

**Update**

Irrational to rational conversion cannot possibly preserve precision. No rational fraction can ever be equal to the relevant irrational number. All we can do is get to the closest value!

---

As a further insight, an enhancement proposal for [inclusion of irrational numbers in `fractions` was rejected](https://bugs.python.org/issue31707).

#### EDIT

If all you want is to display it mathematically in unicode:

```py
from pylatexenc.latex2text import LatexNodes2Text

# To convert some latex unicode input to actual latex output
in_expr_unicode = r"""$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$"""

out_latex = LatexNodes2Text().latex_to_text(in_expr_unicode)

print('          The math formula: ', out_latex)
```

which will output:

```bash
          The math formula:  √(2)/2
```

Comment: This doesn't preserve the precision... It loses it already in the 4th digit

Comment: well irrational to rational conversion is bound lose precision; btw the denominator value can be set!